# analog command grep -o in Powershell

Tags: powershell, grep

What command in Powershell replaces grep -o (which displays only the matched portion of a line instead of a whole line) ?
i try  use Select-Object but it always display full line.
For example:

next line

```
<a id="tm_param1_text1_item_1" class="tm_param1param2_param3 xxx_zzz qqq_rrrr_www_vv_no_empty" >eeee <span id="ttt_xxx_zzz">0</span></a>
```

use next command:

```
cat filename  | grep -o '>[0-9]' | grep -o '[0-9]'
```

output: 0

When i use Select-Object i always see full line (

Comment: I like wheels. So `[regex]$regex = '>[0-9]';$regex.Matches($a)`

Answer (score 5):

One way is:

```
$a = '<a id="tm_param1_text1_item_1" class="tm_param1param2_param3 xxx_zzz qqq_rrrr_www_vv_no_empty" >eeee <span id="ttt_xxx_zzz">0</span></a>'

$a -match '>([0-9])<' #returns true and populate the $matches automatic variable

$matches[1] #returns 0
```

Comment: @user2441498 Glad to help! If you have more digits to match use `+` instead of `*`

Answer (score 4):

For selecting strings in text, use `select-string` rather than `select-object`. It will return a MatchInfo object. You can access the matches by querying the matches property:

```
$a = '<a id="tm_param1_text1_item_1" class="tm_param1param2_param3 xxx_zzz qqq_rrrr_www_vv_no_empty" >eeee <span id="ttt_xxx_zzz">0</span></a>'
($a | select-string '>[0-9]').matches[0].value # returns >0
```

Comment: I like this: `($a | select-string '>([0-9]+)').matches[0].groups[1].value`

Comment: `($a | select-string '>[0-9]').Matches | select Value`

Answer (score 3):

InPowerShell v3:

```
sls .\filename -pattern '^[0-9]' -AllMatches  | % matches | % value
```

Explanation:
sls is an alias for Select-String. It takes a filename/path as well as a pattern as parameters. It produces "matches"

% matches selects all matches regardless of file etc.
% value selects the value of each match

Answer (score 2):

The solutions that have been proposed so far only produce the *first* match from each line. To fully emulate the behavior of `grep -o` (which produces *every* match from each line) something like this is required:

```
Get-Content filename | Select-String '>([0-9])' -AllMatches |
  Select-Object -Expand Matches | % { $_.Groups[1].Value }
```

`Select-String -AllMatches` returns all matches from an input string.

`Select-Object -Expand Matches` "disconnects" matches from the same line, so that all submatches can be selected via `$_.Groups[1]`. Without this expansion the submatch from the second match of a line would be `$_.Groups[3]`.